# Custom settings and Governor limits

Tags: customsetting

Can we write a SOQL query on the custom object?are the actions on the Custom settings are countered against Governor limits?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes,You can write soql query on custom objects.If it comes to custom settings,you can save queries I mean You can access custom setting without using queries using "custom setting methods".

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

If You need to look more difference between custom object v/s custom settings.Please check below link

I have provided  salesforce developer forum link here :

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008mUyIAI

check below salesforce document for Governor Limits:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: can we write a SOQL query on custom setting object?

Comment: see Instead of quires using "custom settings methods",you can directly get the value.custom setting methods serve your query purpose,...but I don't understand why do you very about query!!!!..

Answer (score 3):

If you access the custom settings through the dedicated [Custom Settings Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) then the access are *not* counted against the query governor limits and the desired behavior for hierarchical custom settings results.

However, you can also query the objects and in that case I believe the access *is* counted against the query governor limits.

Bottom line: use the methods (except in rare circumstances).